# создание activity по кнопке

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, activity, android-button

есть кнопка "создать задание", при ее нажатии появляется кнопка "Русский язык", если ее нажать создается новое activity и нас переносит на него. Вопрос: Как реализовать, чтобы нажимая на кнопку появлялась кнопка с привязанным новым activity.

Comment: а почему нельзя создать активити для кнопки и просто переходить на него? или кнопок будет много?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании ваша активити прописывается в манифесте и поэтому программное создание активити невозможно ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313610/dynamically-create-an-activity)). Вот еще подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790607/creating-activity-dynamically). Как решение я могу вам посоветовать два варианта:

1. Вы создаете одну активити, на которую просто пересылаете данные и заполняете ее при переходе. Используя этот вариант вы сможете использовать разные данные на одном активити.
2. Второй вариант чем-то похож на первый только легче - вы работаете с фрагментами. Насколько я знаю фрагменты можно создавать программно. В чем позитив второго варианта - фрагмент легче для устройства и его не нужно прописывать в манифесте. Вот например есть [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296868/how-to-add-a-fragment-to-a-programmatically-generated-layout) или вот еще [решение](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdwhhksnOAM).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.